# How to set the minimum count of digits after the decimal point in Dart?

Tags: dart, format, double, decimal

In my shopping app, I want to show the item's price in two formats. In the currency of my country which is the HUF and we don't use decimals.

> e.g. HUF 1250 or 1250 Ft

The other is the EUR and there we write two digits after the decimal point. These two digits are always there, even if they are 00.

> e.g. EUR 12.00 or 12,00 €

I know how can I set the maximum count of digits with the `double.toStringAsFixed()` method but I didn't find a solution to the opposite setting. Is there in the Dart API any method to solve my problem or do I need to find an alternative way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

You can define the currency with number format like so:

```
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

final oCcy = new NumberFormat("#,##0.00", "en_US");

void main () {

  print("Eg. 1: ${oCcy.format(123456789.75)}");
  print("Eg. 2: ${oCcy.format(.7)}");
  print("Eg. 3: ${oCcy.format(12345678975/100)}");
  print("Eg. 4: ${oCcy.format(int.parse('12345678975')/100)}");
  print("Eg. 5: ${oCcy.format(double.parse('123456789.75'))}");
}
```